# pg_restore throws end of line error when the dump file is edited

Tags: node.js, pg-dump, eol, pg-restore

*using pg_dump to dump the database in a custom format archive*

`pg_dump -U $PG_USER -d $PG_DB -a --column-inserts -Z 0 -Fc > db.dump`

i have to use subquery to create new temporary tables based on the real tables.

now i dump those tables using the above command but i must edit the `db.dump` file in nodejs just to replace a temporary tables names with real tables.

the problem is wheni edit in node by just reading the file and replacing the string with replaceAll it does not get through with pg_restore.

pg_restore throws the below error

`pg_restore: error: could not read from input file: end of file`

perhaps editing binary file is somehow messing up with byte order or end of line ?

Comment: Binary file? Are you not dumping as a SQL file (text)?

Comment: no, i am not dumping as .sql file (text), rather i am using custom archive format and using -Fc flag with .dump extension for the file

Comment: Editing a binary file by hand in a text editor is rarely a good idea. If you know the output format you could use a hex editor but whatever changes you make need to be consistent with that format (eg, are strings 0-term or length-tagged, etc).

Comment: ive actually avoided editing it manually, i assumed the .sql text file would never respect any option in pg_dump (pg_dump docs were not very clear about it) but it did, i just did not try it, now i am using psql to read the .sql  file and it restores the data without any errors. 

thank you for taking the time to comment. you made me ask the why to myself